# Disable embedded video in Live Messenger

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I recently upgraded to a newer version of Live Messenger and when someone sends me a link to a YouTube video via IM Messenger opens the video inside the message.

Does anyone know if this feature can be disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A-Patch](http://apatch.org/downloads/) for Windows Live Messenger is a patcher and with the new 2011 version of Windows Live Messenger, they added two options `Disable Photo Sharing` and `Disable Video Sharing`.

While not actually using those options myself, they should (in theory at least) do what you want.

A-Patch is mostly known for its option to remove advertisements and I have used it every time I install Windows Live Messenger.